# type="datetime-local" in Django form

Tags: python, django

I want to understand Django form.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="deadline">Deadline</label>
  <input
    type="datetime-local"
    class="form-control"
    id="deadline"
    aria-describedby="deadlineHelp"
    placeholder="Enter when deadline"
  />
</div>
```

I want to create this field with Django.
But

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %} {{form.as_p}}</form>
```

to create a simple lines.
And if I fix forms.py like

```
class Create(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('deadline_task',)
        widgets = {
           'deadline_task': forms.DateTimeInput(),
        }
```

It not working.

```
<p><label for="id_deadline_task">Deadline task:</label> <input 
type="text" name="deadline_task" id="id_deadline_task"></p>
```

I just want `<input type="datetime-local"`  - It convenient to select a date.
Thank you.
P.S. `Django 1.11`

Comment: You will need to have a [datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/) framework. Bootstrap provides a good one

Comment: @Lemayzeur https://pastebin.com/3LUyx91a it form look good for me, but I do not know change input type in Django.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue and solved it this way:

```
widgets = {
    'request_date': DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}),
}
```

Comment: This solution isn't perfect. When editing an existing object, Django cannot fill the input with the current datetime value. At least on Firefox, it seems that the attribute value of datetime-local inputs expects something similar to the ISO format (with a T separating date and time). When this is not the case, the field gets blank, and I have to choose the date and time again. Another option to consider is the `SplitDateTimeWidget`.

Answer (score 9):

As pointed out, [the currently accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50666056/219519) displays the correct HTML5 widget, but the value returned from the widget in the frontend will not be accepted by the field validation in the backend.

A working solution is to use a `datetime-local` widget as well as a custom `DateTimeField` recognizing the datetime format:

```py
from django import forms

 
class DateTimeLocalInput(forms.DateTimeInput):
    input_type = "datetime-local"
 
class DateTimeLocalField(forms.DateTimeField):
    # Set DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS here because, if USE_L10N 
    # is True, the locale-dictated format will be applied 
    # instead of settings.DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS.
    # See also: 
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats
     
    input_formats = [
        "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", 
        "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f", 
        "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M",
    ]
    widget = DateTimeLocalInput(format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")


class Form(forms.Form):
    my_datetime_field = DateTimeLocalField()
```